# Python regex to separate the words in the same string

Tags: python-2.7

```
test_text = "AirMail from cairnsReceived but NOTavailable at the postOFFICE"
```

I want to be able to separate the co-joined words and print the same string as

```
print test_text 

test_text = "Air Mail from cairns Received but NOT available at the post OFFICE"
```

I tried the following code but does not work exactly what I want:

```
cleaned_text1 = re.sub(r'([A-Z][^A-Z]*)', r' \1', test_text)
print cleaned_text1
```

I get the following output:

"Air  Mail from cairns  Received but  N O T available at the post  O F F I C E"

Answer (score 0):

The code below should suffice your need.

However if you need to split symbol, it will be another story...
I attached some testcases for you to show which cases this way do not handle. In sum, it doesn't handle trailing space, two or more spaces between words, and symbol.

My way still need improvement, since I use while loop in splitWords function to remedy the flaw in regex.

Hope it helps.

```
import re

def subFunc(matchobj):
    for c in range(len(matchobj.group(0))-1):
        if matchobj.group(0)[c].isupper() != matchobj.group(0)[c + 1].isupper():
            return ' '.join([matchobj.group(0)[:c+1], matchobj.group(0)[c+1:]])


def splitWords(test_text):
    cleaned_text1 = re.sub(r'([a-z][A-Z])|([A-Z]{2,}[a-z])', subFunc, test_text)
    while test_text != cleaned_text1:
        test_text = cleaned_text1
        cleaned_text1 = re.sub(r'([a-z][A-Z])|([A-Z]{2,}[a-z])', subFunc, test_text)

    print cleaned_text1

test_text = "AirMail from cairnsReceived but NOTavailable at the postOFFICE"
goal_text = "Air Mail from cairns Received but NOT available at the post OFFICE"
splitWords(test_text)
# Air Mail from cairns Received but NOT available at the post OFFICE

test_text = "AirMail from cairnsReceived but NOTavailable at the postOFFICEiLovePython"
splitWords(test_text)
# Air Mail from cairns Received but NOT available at the post OFFICE i Love Python

test_text = "AirMailFrOm cairnsReceived butNOTavailable at the postOFFICEiLovePYTHON"
splitWords(test_text)
# Air Mail Fr Om cairns Received but NOT available at the post OFFICE i Love PYTHON

test_text = "  Air..Mail From   cairnsReceived butNOTavailable at the postOFFICEiLovePYTHON"
splitWords(test_text)
#   Air..Mail From   cairns Received but NOT available at the post OFFICE i Love PYTHON
```

Comment: Hi Yen, appreciate your assistance. Will do a few more tests on various kinds of strings and improve the regex if needed.